# Halachot on geirut during times of persecution

Tags: halacha, history, conversion-to-judaism, anti-semitism

I’ve often heard that a reason that conversions take years and require nearly full observance prior to the tevilah is that this we do not live in a period of persecution, but the relatively light requirements in the Shulchan Aruch (and historical conversions) are for periods of persecution since that environment speaks to a converts sincerity. Is that correct?

Secondarily, would one expect conversion requirements in the west to become more lax if the current rise of antisemitism continues?

Comment: What I'd heard is not so much the sincerity of "wanting to convert" but "do you realize this means keeping halacha." That suggestion is put out there, if I'm not mistaken, on why the Rambam has more on the "filtration" process than the Gemara -- in Talmudic times, if you were a Roman and wanted to be Jewish, you knew what that meant -- full halachic observance. In Rambam's time, eh could be Karaite, could be Jewish-lite ... today someone may be all gung-ho about "Jewish identity/nationhood" *amech ami*, but totally miss the boat on halacha / "elokayich elokai."

Comment: thanks. If you'd like you can post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct